# CE Image with Low Variables and Lazy Load: What im doing worng?

Tags: templates, low-variables, ce-image, parsing

what im doing wrong? Im trying load a image via Assets, in a Low Variable field.

Nothing is rendered, but Low Variables field is with "early parsing" enabled. The Lazy Load JQuery plugin is active.

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="myassetsimage"}
    {exp:ce_img:pair src="{myassetsimage}" width="640" height="400" class="img-polaroid" alt=""}
          <img data-original="{made_url}" src="{site_url}layout/img/pic-blank-1.gif">
    {/exp:ce_img:pair}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Comment: Is anything rendering for data-original="" in source code?

Comment: No, Anna, nothing is rendered !!!

Comment: If you're using the tag syntax for Low Variables, having early parsing enabled or disabled is irrelevant. In fact, in this case, it's better to turn it off.

Comment: The strange is:

1. CE Image is rendering data image in channels. I can see this happens in other stuff.

2. Low variables is working, in other custom fields. In the same page, i have it a code parsing matrix data and all is fine.

For some reason, JUST THIS combination of code, nothing is rendering...

Comment: I'd say triple check everything or start with fresh code. It's probably just something not named correctly.

Comment: Im going to go bananas, so i kicked all my code and make this, with CE image in a single pair tag:

`{exp:low_variables:pair var="myassetsimage"}
  {exp:ce_img:single  src="{myassetsimage}" width="640" height="400" class="img-polaroid" alt=""}
 {/exp:low_variables:pair}`


But one more time, DONT RENDER!!!

Comment: Check my answer below...

Comment: Turn on template debugging and look up the actual opening tag of the ce_img. What does that say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, first, **turn off** early parsing for the `myassetsimage` variable. Then try and use Asset's `{url}` variable ([see docs](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/field.html#variable-tags)) in CI Img's src-parameter instead of the Low Variables name. That means that your code would look like this:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="myassetsimage"}
  {exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" width="640" height="400" class="img-polaroid" alt=""}
    <img data-original="{made_url}" src="{site_url}layout/img/pic-blank-1.gif">
  {/exp:ce_img:pair}
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

Comment: I just changed `{made_url}` by `{made}`  and all works !!!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either an issue with field names not being correct or a parsing issues.

To rule out incorrect names triple check everything or start with fresh code.

---

To check parsing, add `parse="inward"` first to the `{exp:low_variables:pair}` tag.

If that doesn't work, remove it and add to `{exp:ce_img:pair}` tag.

If that doesn't work, try adding to both.